# Backbone: properties in ECMAScript 6

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, ecmascript-6

I'm searching for a good ECMAScript 6 equivalent of the following Backbone code:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: MyModel
});
```

This pattern is widely used in Backbone models, views and collections. **Can I do better than the code below (e.g. by creating a method named "model")?**

```
export class MyModel extends Backbone.Model {}

export class MyCollection extends Backbone.Collection {
    constructor() {
        super({model: MyModel});
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you transpiling? If so did you try es7's static keyword which is supported by Babel? `static model = MyModel`

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Backbone has its own class machinery, just keep using it.

Comment: @DominicTobias: I'm using Babel, should I declare static field inside class?
2torazaburo: I'm trying to use a good framework with the newest ECMA version for a new application.

Comment: @vania-pooh yes `static model = MyModel;` where you would have previously done `model: MyModel`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use a getter:

```
export class MyModel extends Backbone.Model {}

export class MyCollection extends Backbone.Collection {
  get model() {
    return MyModel;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, just don't use the `class` keyword:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: MyModel
});
```

This code is actually more reusable than the ECMAScript 6 equivalent you wrote. The ECMAScript 6 is actually worse than the original one.

You have to understand that in JavaScript objects can exist without classes and that feature is extremely important.

Here is what Douglas Crockford wrote on prototypal inheritance back in 2008: http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html

Comment: This was not my downvote, but I'm really in doubt. Why do we need ECMAScript 6 classes feature at all?

Comment: I asked the same question on many forums. Many of them says that partly because people still haven't learned JavaScript properly. Many people who are front-end developers have come from the Java/.Net/PHP world where functions were not really first-class citizens up until recently.

Comment: You are right that we don't *need* class syntax, and I'd hesitate to suggest class syntax for most usecases, but if an application is already using Backbone's class system, it is a 1-1 mapping and using the declarative syntax is absolutely no worse.

Comment: Backbone's class system? I'm not sure how Backbone has a "class system". Yes, it has an extend method which makes people to treat it like they are programming in Java. And I don't understand why my answer should be downvoted. So far, this is the most practical answer in this thread which also contains a link with basic concepts that every JavaScript programmer should know.

Comment: Btw, I'm mainly a Java programmer but I intend to use classes with Backbone just because I'm implementing an application from scratch and ECMA6 is now a standard.

Comment: @akoskm (I didn't downvote) All I'm saying is that Backbone's `.extend` is identical behavior-wise to class syntax, and they are perfectly compatible. If you want to argue about whether class syntax should have been added to the language, SO isn't a good place for it. I disagree with "actually more reusable" though since they are functionally equivalent, it's in the language now, so using one or the other is entirely an code style choice and a team should make.

Comment: @loganfsmyth my point was not to argue. If you look at my answers you'll see that I tend to extend my answers with suggestions/ideas I already tested or implemented somewhere. If I did a research in the past, let's include my findings in the answer! I don't like to provide answers strictly to the question. Some users appreciate this by upvotes, some users don't appreciate it at all and the rest downvotes.